# Pass query results object to separate function

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform, single-page-application

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tenfold/4XsLq/7/) shows more or less what I am trying to do.

I am querying some results from a Parse.com database. The results are returned in the success callback.

Can anyone tell me the best way to work with them in the `mainView()` function? I would like to keep all queries separate from the logic of how they are displayed. I have tried quite a few different approaches, but haven't been able to get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply store a reference to `this` outside the callback.

```
    var userInterface = {


    newQuery: function() {
        var that=this; //store a reference to "this"

        Query = Parse.Object.extend("Test"); 
        query = new Parse.Query(Query);

        query.descending("createdAt");    
        query.equalTo("column1", "a");

        query.find({
            success:function(results){

                 that.mainView(results); //that points to the userInterface object

            },
            error:function(error){

            }


        });
    }, 



    mainView: function(res){

        console.log(res);

    },

    init: function() {
       this.newQuery();        
    }

};
userInterface.init();
```

---

http://jsfiddle.net/4XsLq/8/